# Test where ID not in (n, n1, n2)

Tags: php, arrays

Given a value, #some_id = x, what's the proper syntax or method to test that the id does not exist in a collection of id's?

For example...

```
if($some_id not in array(3, 5, 9)){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$theArray = array(3, 5, 9);

if(! in_array($x, $theArray)){
    // do something
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: You beat me by a couple seconds :/

Answer (score 1):

> in_array
>   too slow

```
$array = array_flip($array);

if(!isset($array[$some_id])){ // do something }
```

Comment: You are right it IS faster, but in most cases it doesn't matter, and in_array is much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The in_array answers are correct, but in case there's some ambiguity between the term "id" and "key", if what you're trying to do is check if a key exists, you could do either of the following:

```
if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) ...
```

or...

```
if (isset($array[$key])) ...
```